# Progress Bar while downloading image in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

Hello Stackoverflowers,
    I will be short, so my question is :
    How can i show a progress-bar in my application while my image is being downloaded?
    I did some research,and i found something about "preloader" and "splach-screen", but we can use these last only before starting my main-application, and   about progress bar, i know i have to bind it, but how can i bind it with my image ? 
    I appreciate any kind of help.

this is my code of creating a simple slide show :

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{

    All_photos photos = (All_photos) new parse_object <All_photos> (All_photos.class).ParseUri("https://api.edmunds.com/api/media/v2/styles/"+id+"/photos?api_key=wdxg7wh338vac3359m34qjj6&fmt=json");

    Images = new ArrayList<Image>();

    ArrayList<String> list_href = new SlideShowHelper().get_href(photos);

    for ( String st:list_href)
    {
        System.out.println(st);
        Images.add(new Image("https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com"+st+""));
    }
    }
```

just to know, that image take a while to be downloaded, it depends on internet connection speed.

Comment: this might be of help - http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: What thread is `init()` being called on? Can you explain the parts of the code you haven't shown, and what you want to happen - i.e. this is downloading a collection of images, presumably, so is it enough to just update the progress bar when each image completes download? Do you really need to download all the images up front like this - why don't you just use the built-in background loading in the `Image` class?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my code, it's simple :1-  save all my photos link in a object called All_photos,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help, i found the answer :

```
 final Task<ArrayList<Image>> task = new Task<ArrayList<Image>>() {
            @Override protected ArrayList<Image> call() throws Exception {

                int id = Data_model.getInstance().currentid();

                All_photos photos = (All_photos) new parse_object <All_photos> (All_photos.class).ParseUri("https://api.edmunds.com/api/media/v2/styles/"+id+"/photos?api_key=id&fmt=json");

                ArrayList<String> list_href = new SlideShowHelper().get_href(photos);

                ArrayList<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();

                int i = 1;

                            for ( String st:list_href)
                            {

                                System.out.println(st);
                                list.add(new Image("https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com"+st+"",true));
                                updateProgress(i, list_href.size());
                                Thread.sleep(400);
                                i++;


                            }
                            return list;
            }


             @Override protected void succeeded() {

                 super.succeeded();

                 updateProgress(10, 10);

                 img_slideshow.setImage(Images.get(0));

                 int count1 =count+1;

                 lbl_slideshow.setText(""+count1+" / "+Images.size()+"");

                 progress_sd.setVisible(false);  

                 btn_sd_back.setVisible(true);
                 btn_sd_next.setVisible(true);


             }


         };

        task.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED,new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                Images = task.getValue();

            }
        });

    new Thread(task).start();


    //progress_sd.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());

    progress_sd.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

}
```

it's working, But ? is it good ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer answers your question title: "Progress Bar while downloading image in javafx".

The code in your question is a bit unclear, so the answer may or may not answer what you really wish to achieve.

[image: bear]

1. Load the image in the [background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-boolean-).
2. Bind the progress property of the ProgressBar to the [progessProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#progressProperty--) of the image.

*Note:* for the sample code and image, the image loads very quickly so you don't actually see the progress bar moving.  For a *very* large image being loaded and a *very* slow internet connection, you may see the progress bar move as the loading progresses.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageLoadProgress extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_LOC =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-10/128/Bear-icon.png";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Image image = new Image(IMAGE_LOC, true);
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
        bar.progressProperty().bind(image.progressProperty());

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setFitWidth(128);
        imageView.setFitHeight(128);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(5, bar, imageView)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Update for additional question*

> how can i create a task with several images being downloaded and one progress bar ?

Use a DoubleExpression which is maps to the average of the background loading progress of all to the images.

[image: multiple images]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleExpression;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ImagesLoadProgress extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_PATH_PREFIX =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-10/128/";

    private static final String[] IMAGES_FILENAMES = {
            "Bear-icon.png",
            "Bow-icon.png",
            "Sport-american-football-icon.png",
            "Sport-baseball-icon.png"
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Image[] images =
                Arrays.stream(IMAGES_FILENAMES)
                .map(filename -> new Image(IMAGE_PATH_PREFIX + filename, true))
                .toArray(Image[]::new);

        DoubleExpression totalImageDownloadProgress;
        if (images.length > 0) {
            totalImageDownloadProgress = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
            for (Image image: images) {
                totalImageDownloadProgress = totalImageDownloadProgress.add(image.progressProperty());
            }
            totalImageDownloadProgress = totalImageDownloadProgress.divide(IMAGES_FILENAMES.length);
        } else {
            totalImageDownloadProgress = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);
        }


        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
        bar.progressProperty().bind(totalImageDownloadProgress);

        VBox layout = new VBox(5, bar);

        Arrays.stream(images)
                .map(this::createImageView)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(layout::getChildren));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ImageView createImageView(Image image) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setFitWidth(128);
        imageView.setFitHeight(128);

        return imageView;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The solution above does not account for [error conditions for images that fail to load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#errorProperty), but I'll leave adding such logic up to you (essentially monitor the error property and adjust the average calculation for the loading progress to not include those images which fail to load).

Comment: Thank you Jewelsea, it's a simple example, and i already understand it and found it before asking my question, how can i create a task with several images being downloaded and one progress bar ?